# Allow user to Landscape Right and Left without using Auto Rotation

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

I tried using the `SystemChrome` to change the orientation and it works for Lock ScreenOrientation. But As i provided two orientation. Application takes the first orientation until user start the Auto Orientation from Setting.

```
SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeLeft,
    DeviceOrientation.landscapeRight,
]);
```

Is it possible to allow user to change the orientation without using Auto-Orientation Service ?

Comment: Do you want to be able to change the orientation manually or do you want to be able to have the user rotate their device and have it turn automatically without auto-rotate on?

Comment: turn automatically without auto-rotation on

Comment: Let me make sure I understand. You want to ignore the rotation lock of the phone and rotate anyways? I think that's grounds to be rejected from the iOS store. Not sure about google. But if you want it you need to read the accelerometer data

Comment: @kent i want to rotate only in landscape right and left

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey @Ashish I found one link for you for Orientation functionality and Concept

[SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientation](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/13238)

Comment: I tried check that code now i am working on own rotation code.

Answer (score 1):

It works only with `android` devices:
add attribute to main activity in `AndroidManifest.xml`

```xml
<activity
    android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
    ...
```

and now screen retains landscape orientation, but can be either normal or reverse landscape based on the device sensor. The sensor is used even if the user has locked sensor-based rotation.

Comment: i tried this way also sir but not working as expected

Answer (score 0):

The idea here is using make a sensor plugin to take only the screen orientation landscape info. Sensor will work even user locks the orientation.

https://www.techrepublic.com/article/pro-tip-use-android-sensors-to-detect-orientation-changes/

From the flutter site, put a listener somewhere and take a rotation programmatically by setPreferredOrientations method.

https://master-api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setPreferredOrientations.html